# Remove unwanted space in input field below text

Tags: html, css

I have an input field like this in my html:

[image: HTML Input field]

CSS for input fields:

```
.form-control-1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transition: width 1s;
  outline: none;
}
```

CSS that overrides some of the CSS rules defined above in mobile viewport ( < 768px):

```
.m-form-control-1 {
  width: 100% !important;
  line-height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

The problem I am having now is I cant seem to remove the space between the placeholder "Username" and the input field's border-bottom with `line-height:0` and `padding:0`.

I also tried having negative value for the bottom margin. Eg. `margin-bottom:-5%` but it still does not work?

How can I remove the unwanted space?

**Note:** I only have this problem in mobile view. (<768px)

**JS Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/quwswery/

Comment: please provide a fiddle or something

Comment: @Fribu Done. As you will see, there is a small unwanted space between the `border-bottom` and the placeholder "Username" that i want to remove.

Comment: Remove the height

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vp47cnjh/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `height:auto` to `form-control-1` or you can remove height either.

```css
.m-form-control-1 {
  width: 100% !important;
  line-height: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: -5% !important;
}

.form-control-1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #555;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  transition: width 1s;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="m-form-control-1 form-control-1" id="username" name="username" data-ng-model="username" data-ng-minlength="8" data-ng-maxlength="20" data-ng-pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z]+" required data-ng-focus="disableUsernameWarning()"
  data-ng-blur="enableUsernameWarning()" data-ng-required placeholder="Username" />
```

Comment: @downvoter, Explain your downvote so I can improve my answer.